# Plotly click callback for a heatmap

Tags: plotly

I'd like to have a heatmap where clicking on a given point triggers an event based on the point location.
The following scheme works for a plotly scatterplot but not for a heat map

```
L = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
f = go.FigureWidget()
f.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=L))
f['layout'].update(width=500, height=500, autosize=False)
def click_callback(trace, points, selector):
    print("Click")
f.data[0].on_click(click_callback)
f.show()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

But your code is actually working fine in a Jupyter notebook. The click event appears as expected:

[image]

Comment: OK, the difference was that you used "f" while I used "f.show()". With this change it now works on a locally hosted notebook.. but not on Google Colab!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in jupyter lab and this is how I worked around.

For some environment, you may need to import `Output` and `VBox` from `ipywidgets`.
Then put a wrapper on your function (`@out.capture()`).

Example:

```
from ipywidgets import Output, VBox
L = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
f = go.FigureWidget()
f.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=L))
f['layout'].update(width=500, height=500, autosize=False)

out = Output()
@out.capture(clear_output=True)
def click_callback(trace, points, selector):
    print("Click")

f.data[0].on_click(click_callback)
VBox([f, out])
```

see:
https://community.plotly.com/t/interactive-graph-click-event/19219/3